# iOS 7.1 Breaks UITabbar Images Selected State

Tags: ios7, uitabbar

Since updating to iOS 7.1, my tab bar images initialize as if they were all active, they are all highlighted on launch. Once I visit each tab, that tab image resets and displays correctly. Has anyone else seen this behavior? Suggestions for work around?

Comment: mine was when app launch no display of the tabbar items except for the selected tab and when tap all goes back to normal...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In my case, as I finally figured out, this issue was caused by setup of appearance protocol on `UIView` in my style controller which is called at startup.

I had been setting an overall tint color for `UIView`. It did not apply to the icons in iOS7.0 but that must have changed in 7.1.

My style code:

```
  // Color for buttons and enabled controls
  UIView *viewAppearance = [UIView appearance];
  [viewAppearance setTintColor:overallTintColor];
```

I added this to fix:

```
  [[UIView appearanceWhenContainedIn:[UITabBar class], nil] setTintColor:[UIColor darkGrayColor]];
```

darkGrayColor is not ideal, I just threw it in there for testing. I tried using nil, as I would like it to just go back to the default as it used to. Giving nil as a color did not have any effect. I suppose I will play with some color values until I get a close match.

Answer (score 0):

I rolled back my xcode to version 5.0, which the only old version i have and build the app using it. It works perfectly on iOS7.1 device now.

If you have the xcode version 5.0.2 that would be great also.

Comment: I downloaded my app from the store and it has the same issues on 7.1 so its not Xcode

Comment: mine works perfectly on app store or install directly xcode now.

Comment: I don't think it is serious enough issue that I would consider all that. I wonder if a bug has been reported, perhaps will wait and see if fixed in next update.

Comment: Check your image sizes, mine were a tiny bit different between each and weren't the recommended 39x39 either once I fixed all this its fine